# how pcap handles multiple protocols simultaneously

Tags: linux, sockets, pcap, packet-sniffers

The documentation for the `int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);` API says that the *protocol* specifies a particular protocol if more than one protocol exists for the given *domain*. This seems to imply that only one protocol can be specified for a given domain for a given socket.

I was experimenting with raw sockets in Linux, but then I stumbled on this *protocol* thing. I know pcap library can be used to capture packets for any protocol. I wrote a Q&D program using pcap and I've noticed most the common protocols defined in `if_ether.h` file were captured.

So currently in my program I can only specify one type of packets to be captured. Are there ways to replicate pcap behavior with standard Linux headers and libraries? How does pcap achieve that? I tried to google the question, but I think my query was ill-formed cause the results I got back weren't much useful.

I am not trying to solve anything here, just learning the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, with the 2.0 or later kernel, libpcap captures on a socket where `domain` is `PF_PACKET`, `type` is either `SOCK_RAW` or `SOCK_DGRAM`, and `protocol` is `htons(ETH_P_ALL)`.

`SOCK_RAW` will, for most network interfaces, give you packets with a link-layer header; for some other interfaces, such as PPP interfaces, it will give you packets *without* the link-layer header, which makes it difficult to determine what protocol is running on top of the link-layer protocol.

`SOCK_DGRAM` will give you packets without the link-layer header, but with some additional information; libpcap uses that information to generate [a fake link-layer header](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL.html).  You would have to write your own code to process that additional information.

See [the Linux packet(7) man page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man7/packet.7.php) for more information.